# Extracting patterns from a string

Tags: r, arrays, stringr

I have been trying to extract multiple string patterns from a string.

Using the library stringr in R there is the option str_extract and str_extract_all. I have used this last one but the problem is that it extracts each time one of the multiple patterns happens and I would like just to keep one ocurrance. With str_extract_ all

```
examples <- c("G06F", "G06F", "H04L", "H04L", "H04L", "H04L", "H04L")
```

turns into

```
c("G06", "G06", "H04", "H04","H04","H04", "H04")
```

and

```
"B01J", "B01J", "B22F", "B22F", "B22F", "G01N"
```

turns into

```
c("B01", "B01", "B22", "B22", "B22", "G01")
```

I would like the output to be `c("G06","H04")` and `c("B01","B22","G01")`. Meaning just keeping a unique ocurrance of the multiple pattern extract

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: The `unique()` function seems handy here.

Comment: Or use `str_which()` to detect IDs of the vector elements

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, none of the stringr packages provide a built in way of removing duplicate matches. The solution is, as [Martin said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74488793/extracting-patterns-from-a-string#comment131492477_74488793), to use `unique()`:

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(examples, "^[A-Z][0-9]{2}") |>  unique() # [1] "G06" "H04"
```